# how to decode a url in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url, decode

This line says server is not declared.

```
Dim DecodedString As String = server.UrlDecode(context.Request.Form("DeckName"))
```

I have imports system.web at the top. cannot seem to figure out why its not working.

Answer (score 15):

Use `HttpUtility` instead.

```
Dim decodedUrl As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedUrl)
```

More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is old and K3N already provided a great answer.. but I believe the 's' in 'server' should be capitalized in your code. That may have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Net

Dim DecodedString As String = WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Form("DeckName"))
```

This should work for vb.net. I tried the HttpUtility but it doesn't recognize even i imported System.Web.