# Replace URL encoded characters to normal characters?

Tags: vb.net, decode

On Visual Basic 2010, I have a text box with this text:

```
%29%3Aeng%3A%28
```

How can I decode this?

I know, if I decode this then I will get:

```
):eng:(
```

And how can I decode another special characters?

Comment: `urldecode()`. BTW: what's that "Visual Basic" doing there?

Comment: It's not specific to PHP. This is just an encoded url.

Comment: I have edited your question to reflect you're talking about decode the encoded URL on Visual Basic and not PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to decode a url in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350192/how-to-decode-a-url-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("%29%3Aeng%3A%28") 'prints ):eng:(
```

should do the trick.