# How can I use decode encoded URL using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms

I have an encoded url as follows;

```
dim inStr As String ="https%3A%2F%2Fmyweb%2page1%2Egov%2Emy%3A448%2Fserver%2FForm%3Fuserid%3Dtrouble"
```

I want to decode the url and assign this url to my `webBrowser` control.

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350192/how-to-decode-a-url-in-vb-net):

```
Dim decodedUrl As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedUrl)
```

I got a snippet to decode but am not using web application, am using `windows application`; can anyone suggest me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` method as follows:

```
    Dim inputURL As String = "https%3A%2F%2Fmypage%2Eme%2Epage%2Esample%3A448%2Flfserver%2FForm%3Fuserid%3DTrouble"
    Dim outputURL As String = Uri.UnescapeDataString(inputURL)
```

The output will be **https://mypage.me.page.sample:448/lfserver/Form?userid=Trouble**